# string output in assembler

Tags: assembly, input

```
c1 segment para public 'code'
assume cs:c1, ds:d1, ss:st1
start:        
                   mov ax, d1
                   mov ds,ax

                   mov ah,9
                   mov dx, offset mess1
                   int 21h

                   mov in_str, 23
                   mov ah,10
                   mov dx, offset in_str
                   int 21h

                   mov si, offset in_str+2
    mov di, offset out_str

                  mov cl, in_str+1
                  xor ch, ch

one:          mov al,[si]
                 cmp al,0A0h;
        JE next
                 cmp al,19h; 
        JBE next1
                 cmp al,96h;
        JBE next    
next1:       mov [di],al;вывод 
                 inc di;
next:        inc si;
                loop one
                
                
                mov ah,9
                mov dx, offset mess2
                int 21h

                mov ah,9
                mov dx, offset out_str
                int 21h

                mov ax, 4c00h
                int 21h
st1 ends
end  start
```

It is my cod in assembler.The program should read an array of numbers from the keyboard.See if the numbers belong to a certain interval and display them on the screen.It does not output sorted array - out_str.Help me,please

Comment: Have you tried single step debugging?  Try that using a short input.

Comment: Doesn't AH=9 / `int 21h` need a `$` terminator at the end of the string?  Besides that, your code doesn't appear to be trying to sort.  Do you just mean "filtered", or do you really want to sort, so if you input "hello" it would output "ehllo"?  If the latter, you could Insertion Sort as you add valid characters to the array, instead of appending them at the end.